# Funcion Switch por If, else

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de resolver un ejercicio en donde tengo que convertir un bloque if a switch.La consigna es

**El objetivo de este ejercicio es imprimir en consola un texto que irá variando según el día que contenga la variable dia. Para esto, ya presentamos un código hecho con if/else que tendremos que modificar y convertirlo a un switch, manteniendo el mismo resultado.**

El codigo original es:

```
let dia = 'jueves'
function finDeSemana (dia) {    
   if (dia == 'viernes') {
       console.log('buen finde')
   } else if (dia == 'lunes') {
       console.log('buena semana')
   } else {
       console.log('buen dia')
    }
}
```

y este es el que hago yo

```
let  finDeSemana = dia
switch (dia) {  
    case 'viernes':
        console.log('buen finde');
        break;
    case 'lunes':
        console.log('buena semana');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('buen dia')

}
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema?

Comment: por ejemplo, me tira un error ThrowError: dia is not defined

Comment: Entiendo que es por la definición de la función. Estás haciendo una igualdad `let findesemana = dia` en vez de poner `function findesemana(día) {`

Comment: Lo único que tienes que cambiar es el bloque `if`.el resto (el let y el función) debes dejarlo como estaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasar los if/else lo has hecho bien, pero no lo que hay fuera. En el código original se usa una función que no has implementado en el nuevo. "finDeSemana" que era el nombre de la función lo has definido como variable. Y "dia" que era una variable no la defines y por eso te da error. La transcripción sería:

```
let dia = 'jueves';

function finDeSemana(dia)
{
    switch (dia) {  
        case 'viernes':
            console.log('buen finde');
            break;
        case 'lunes':
            console.log('buena semana');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('buen dia')
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el segundo código no está definido dia, está definido finDeSemana y luego dentro del Switch estas haciendo el condicional a "día"..
Si es eso, lo resolverías reemplazando la linea 1 del segundo ejercicio por la del primero, donde declaras la constante. La otra forma es pasarle al switch "finDeSemana" y asignarle a finDeSemana un día X como string.
Ej:

```
let dia = "lunes"

switch (dia) {  
    case 'viernes':
        console.log('buen finde');
        break;
    case 'lunes':
        console.log('buena semana');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('buen dia')

}
```